# Why do Visualforce pages require invalid HTML? (at times)

Tags: salesforce, visualforce, salesforce-lightning

This has happened to me a couple times. Using something like an `<img>` tag, or `<br>`. Basically any HTML void element. Just today I attempted to use a `<br>`, and when saving got this:

[image: error message screen shot]

Am I missing something?

Is there a reason for this?

Are void elements not intended for use in visualforce pages or components?

Or is this just flawed syntax checking?

Can be very frustrating at times, I ended up adding a false  tag the other day because I realized it wouldn't be rendered and it was the only way to save my page...

P.S. I'm sorry if this has an easily accessible answer. I think I looked a reasonable amount, but not as much as usual before posting a question. Just couldn't even find search terms to get me close to something relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visualforce must be a valid **XML** document. Not HTML (which permits `<img>` without closing), not XHTML (because if you add any `<apex:...` tags not defined by W3C officially it's not a html document anymore, at least until it gets compiled and output becomes pure html0.

So you need `<img> ... </img>` or self-closing version, `<img />`.
In a way Lightning Web Components are even worse, self-closing doesn't work. Has to be explicit "end tag".

As to why... probably for easier ability to parse it as a valid document? I suspect they did it also for easier PDF generation.

This isn't exactly same topic but close enough I could find in reasonable time: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_styling_doctype.htm